# Correct way to insert button value into my input (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some sort of calculator, and I need to insert `.num-pad_number.html()` into my input. Is that correct way to do this:

```
$("#num-pad").on("click", ".num-pad_number", function (event) {
    $("#calc-input").val($("#calc-input").val() + $(this).html());
});
```

Or it may be more convinient and correct way? Cuz I have some bug with that solution. After some manipulations with websockets, "calculator" starts to duplicate every number, for example I need "5" but it insert "55".

Comment: Input.val() and $(this).html() both gives you an string of a number and by default they join as string not sum like numbers.
`'5' + '5' = '55' not 10;`

Comment: You want to append the value of the button that's being clicked?

Comment: Use `.text()` not `.html()` since you won't be adding HTML, only the text content.

Comment: @Gustaf Gunér Yes!

Comment: @Farid Naderi yeah, I need to append numbers.

Comment: maybe after some manipulations you forgot to clear input value

Comment: @BimBam uh I see :) .. well I think if you provide more parts of your code like HTML and JS codes.. we can help you easier. because the above code looks ok, so maybe the problem comes from somewhere else . like re-attaching the click event handler to your calc buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly modified. Using `.text()` instead of `.html()`. Shorter event function. Working example below:

```js
$('#num_pad .num-pad_number').click(function() {
  $("#calc-input").val($("#calc-input").val() + $(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="calc-input" type="text"/>

<div id="num_pad">
  <button class="num-pad_number">1</button>
  <button class="num-pad_number">2</button>
  <button class="num-pad_number">3</button>
  <button class="num-pad_number">4</button>
  <button class="num-pad_number">5</button>
  <button class="num-pad_number">6</button>
  <button class="num-pad_number">7</button>
  <button class="num-pad_number">8</button>
  <button class="num-pad_number">9</button>
</div>
```